# Reverse Lookup for Inherited Models in Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance, foreign-keys

I have several Django model definitions. There is a parent class contains a foreign key to another class, and there are multiple model classes that inherit from the parent.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Parent(models.Model):
    foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Child1(Parent):
    pass

class Child2(Parent):
    pass
```

Given an object of type Foo, I am trying to perform a reverse lookup to find all objects that are either of type Parent or subclass Parent and that link to that specific object. However, if I use `foo.parent_set` I would only get the objects of the Parent class that are related to foo, while if I try doing so with any of the child classes it errors out because those don't directly specify a relationship with the class Foo.

Is there any way to get a list of all objects that are of type Parent or inherit from Parent that contain a foreign key to an object of type Foo?

Comment: The `foo.parent_set` will also contain `Parent`s that are instances of `Child1`, `Child2`, etc.

Comment: A subclass of `Parent` is in essence just another model, with a `parent_ptr` to `Parent`, and Django's magic that makes querying, etc. more convenient. But inheritance, in relational tables, is really painful. Usually one should try to avoid this *at all cost*.

Comment: Thank you. Is it still a bad idea if I don't never instantiate the parent object directly?